# Network data in SQL Server - identifying separate routes

Tags: t-sql, search, networking, neural-network

I am looking for help with a database task, which probably will be easier to solve by some object programming language. At this moment I keep trying to find TSQL/SQL Server solution of it.

I use a source table which contains data about routes. Each record describes a link of a route with routeNo, originNodeID and destinationNodeID. The most complicated example of data from this table looks like below:

```
routeID originNodeID destinationNodeID
 WRTV    ...             ...
 WRTX    5               10
 WRTX    10              15
 WRTX    15              20
 WRTX    20              25
 WRTX    25              30
 WRTX    25              1505
 WRTX    25              2005
 WRTX    30              35
 WRTX    30              1005
 WRTX    35              40
 WRTX    40              45
 WRTX    45              50
 WRTX    1005            1010
 WRTX    1015            1020
 WRTX    1505            1510
 WRTX    1510            1515 
 WRTX    2005            2010
 WRTX    2010            2015 
 WRTX    2020            2025 
 WRTY    ....            ....
```

So, as you can see each routeID describes not a linear route but route with branches. The route from the example may look like this:

```
               1515    1020
                /     /
               /     /
   5 ------ 25 --- 30 -------50  
              \
               \
                2025
```

Now, what I need to do is to dismember this route to separate routes:

5-25-30-50     WRTX1
5-25-30-1020   WRTX2
5-25-1515      WRTX3
5-25-2025      WRTX4

For each of the new routes I just need the link sequence like below:

```
routeID originNodeID destinationNodeID
     WRTX1    5               10
     WRTX1    10              15
     WRTX1    15              20
     WRTX1    20              25
     WRTX1    25              30
     WRTX1    30              35
     WRTX1    35              40
     WRTX1    40              45
     WRTX1    45              50
     WRTX2    5               10
     WRTX2    10              15
     WRTX2    15              20
     WRTX2    20              25
     WRTX2    25              30
     WRTX2    30              1005
     WRTX2    1005            1010
     WRTX2    1015            1020 
     WRTX3    5               10
     WRTX3    10              15
     WRTX3    15              20
     WRTX3    20              25
     WRTX3    25              1505
     WRTX3    1505            1510
     WRTX3    1510            1515 
     WRTX4    5               10
     WRTX4    10              15
     WRTX4    15              20
     WRTX4    20              25
     WRTX4    25              2005
     WRTX4    2005            2010
     WRTX4    2010            2015 
     WRTX4    2020            2025
```

Do you have any idea how to solve my problem ? Preferably I would like to make this solution in SQL Server, but I had only little experience in loops and cursors which possibly could be useful in that case. Once I even made an ETL, but it was working only when there was only one point where the route splits.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Is this really a graph or a hierarchy displayed left to right? It looks like you are asking for all *leaves* and their path to the root. You could add a [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) column. Each hierarchyid value essentially encodes the path to the root, converting hierarchy searches to range searches. This means that you can use an index on a hierarchyid column to speed up searches

Comment: The [Converting a Table to a Hierarchical Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677237.aspx) tutorial shows how you can convert a Parent/Child table to a table with hierarchyid columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the actions you need to program in sql. There is no universal programming languages. Some action needs to be done in other programming languages. For your tasks it is better suited to additionally use python with sql databases.

You can edit a row in python and insert into the database. Can you give an example script, but you must bring the correct string "5-25-30-50 WRTX1 5-25-30-1020 WRTX2 5-25-1515 WRTX3 5-25-2025 WRTX4" and correct example of a data table.

In your table there is the number 10, but they are not in the line above. In this regard, do not understand the mechanism of decomposition of the string "5-25-30-50 WRTX1 5-25-30-1020 WRTX2 5-25-1515 WRTX3 5-25-2025 WRTX4". For example, "5-25-30-50 WRTX1" decompose ""5 25 WRTX1", ""25 30 WRTX1", ""30 50 WRTX1"? And so on?

EXAMPLE FOR PYTHON + MSSQL

```
import pymssql
import re
ServName = 'YourMSSQLServName'
DBName = 'YourDBName'

conn = pymssql.connect(server=ServName, database=DBName)
cursor = conn.cursor()
querytxt = '''
INSERT INTO [routing]
           ([routeID] ,[originNodeID] ,[destinationNodeID])
VALUES
           ('@routeID', @originNodeID , @destinationNodeID)'''
limit = 1000
Mask = 'WRTX'
F = open('rote.txt', 'r')
L = [R.strip() for R in F]
for Line in L:
    LineLast = Line  
    j = 1
    while len(LineLast) != 0:
        PingLines = LineLast.partition(Mask)[0].strip()
        LineTemp = LineLast.partition(Mask)[2].strip()
        Num = LineTemp[0]    
        LineLast = LineTemp.partition(' ')[2]
        PingSet = PingLines.split('-')        
        i = 0
        while i < len(PingSet)-1:
            Ping1 = PingSet[i]
            Ping2 = PingSet[i+1]
            i = i + 1            
            routeID = Mask + Num
            originNodeID = Ping1
            destinationNodeID = Ping2
            print('Mask = %s\tPing1 = %s\tPing2 = %s' % (routeID , originNodeID, destinationNodeID))
            query = querytxt.replace('@routeID', routeID)
            query = query.replace('@originNodeID', originNodeID)
            query = query.replace('@destinationNodeID', destinationNodeID)
            cursor.execute(query)
            conn.commit()
            if i >= limit : break        
        j = j + 1
        if j >= limit : break
F.close()
```

Comment: An imperative language can work with one item at a time. A relational databases works with *sets* of data, in the same time it takes an imperative language to process a few rows and scale much better. A graph database will be even faster.  There *are* techniques for dealing with graphs, hierarchies and networks in SQL. Sometimes, you can get much better performance for hierarchies with a relational database and eg nested sets, that you could with an imperative language and recursion

Comment: I agree that `There is no universal programming languages.`

Comment: For this specific problem, even in imperative languages, you need to find the appropriate algorithms for tree or graph walking. A simple loop or recursion would result in an infinite loop if there was even a single loop in the graph. Even if there are multiple small trees, why check *all* nodes when only the leaves are of interest? Even if we only check the leaves, how do we avoid goind up the hierarchy to the root for each one of them?

Comment: What if a node acquired a path property when it was added to the tree? Then you'd only have to read the path property of the leaves. Well, a `hierarchyid` type in T-SQL is just such a path